# How to stop a UITableview from scrolling horizontally?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

For some reason my iOS UITableView is scrolling horizontally. Any ideas why this may happen?

Thanks.

Edit: It seems to be the result of repositioning the table in code with screen reorientation. So I guess the question is: how do I reposition the table and not get the horizontal/diagonal scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IB - in the Inspector for the UIScrollView, there is an option for "Scrollers" - with checkboxes for "Vertical" and "Horizontal". You can check/uncheck these to enable/prohibit scrolling on these axises.

Perhaps the larger issue at hand is that you need to *resize* your views to match the screen orientation, so that you don't wind up with a mismatch between the viewable rectangle and the scroll rectangle.

Comment: The mismatch between the scroll and content sizes was indeed the issue. Once I took care of that, it's all good.

Comment: @raheel How did you take care of the mismatch between the scroll and content sizes?